# Probable Cypher issue - Neo4J query runs out of memory and server stalls

Tags: memory, neo4j, cypher, heap-memory

I'm running into an issue with Neo4J where the system runs out of memory performing my query. I've already increased the size of the heap to 3GB, which results in the same issue, just that it takes longer to run out of memory at the same point of the injestion of a dataset (I am a long way into the injestion process so there is already substantial amount of data in the database but it's not that much. DB is 350MB, there are 176780 nodes and 259463 relationships).

That is to say, I send my query through the REST interface with node to Neo4J and it becomes unresponsive. There is no reply for a long time, and eventually it tells me it ran out of memory. The only thing that the increase in heap size did was make this timeout longer. In the debug log I see that the garbage collector completely hammering the application thread. It does seem to be working fine for a large initial portion of the data, and I'm not quite sure what's going on here.

I feel this might be an issue related to doing something silly with my queries, hence I have added the code examples below in the hopes of that someone spots a mistake in case it exists.

Firstly, what I want to achieve:

- Query 1 simply pushes creates nodes if they are new and relates if the relationship is new (this is data read from a CSV through node.js)
- With query 2 I am basically saying: look for any node of label "HashInput" that matches the value I am giving you for a certain key (e-mail), then find any "CustomerHash" node that it is connected to, and any other "CustomerHash" that shares an indirect relationship (through a shared HashInput) with this node. If any of those "HashNodes" relate to more than 1 "customerNode". In that case, those customerNodes have to be merged into a single node and the properties concatted.

To show this a bit more visually, in the following image A and B have to be merged. The combined total of "CustomerNodes" for the two "CustomerHashes" (but could be n amount of nodes, hence the unbounded search) that are related through the "HashInput" is > 1 thus they need to be merged.

[image: Schema]

Then the actual queries:

Query 1):
I am generating a cypher query here, which comes down to:

```
`
MERGE (base: ${labels} { ${stringifiedProperties} } )

WITH base
MATCH (connectingNode: ${labelsConnectingNode} { ${ connetingNodeProperties } } )
MERGE ( base )-[r:${relationshipLabell}  { ${ relationshipProperties } } ]->(connectingNode)
`
```

Query 2 (this is the one that blocks) ):

```
`
MATCH
(seed:HashInput { customer_email: '${cleanEmail}' })-[:CONSISTS_OF*]-(Hashes:CustomerHash)
    -[:IS_LIKELY_CUSTOMER]->
(CustomerNodes:Customer)

WITH
count( DISTINCT ID( CustomerNodes ) ) AS countCustomerNodes,
collect(CustomerNodes) as CustomerNodesList,
collect(Hashes) as hashList,
collect(DISTINCT Hashes._customer_email) as eMails,
collect(DISTINCT Hashes._card_fingerprint) as cardFingerprints

WHERE countCustomerNodes > 1

MERGE (newCustomerNode:Person:Customer { eMails: 0, cardFingerprints : 0 })
SET newCustomerNode.eMails = eMails
SET newCustomerNode.cardFingerprints = cardFingerprints

WITH
hashList,
CustomerNodesList,
newCustomerNode

UNWIND hashList as Hashes

WITH
Hashes,
CustomerNodesList,
newCustomerNode

UNWIND CustomerNodesList as CustomerNodes

DETACH DELETE CustomerNodes
MERGE (Hashes)-[r:IS_LIKELY_CUSTOMER]->(newCustomerNode)
`
```

Comment: how many of query (1) do you send in per transaction? You should use parameters not substitution if possible.

Comment: do you have a constraint on HashInput(customer_email) ? That unbounded var-length pattern will potentionally return millions or billions of paths

Comment: you do the same match time and again, that doesn't make any sense, keep the paths and use them, limit the var-length to an upper limit and add a direction for your CONSISTS_OF

Comment: Perhaps it's best to go back to square one and explain what you actually want to do. Also let us know your data model and your data sizes.

Comment: Apologies, I clarified the post a little bit more with a picture and a bit of clearer text. Regarding replicating the match, I will re-test tomorrow but if I recall correctly I had to do this because was seemingly unable to carry that "Hashes:" match through without problems (with a "WITH" statement). I do think there is a rookie mistake at play here from my side.

Comment: I added an update regarding why I used multiple matches. I do not have a constraint set up, but seeing as I am using "MERGE" and the only property is the e-mail, there is ever only one node with that data. If I am not mistaken. DB is 350MB, there are 176780 nodes and 259463 relationships. Query 1 has 100 queries in a batch.

Comment: Can you add the output of an EXPLAIN of your query (after expanding all elements of the query plan)? Or a PROFILE, if you're able to add limits in your query so that it can finish executing on a smaller set of data?

Comment: Note that you can avoid the multiple match issue with: `WITH count(CustomerNodes) AS countCustomerNodes, 
CustomerNodes, collect(Hashes) as hashList WHERE countCustomerNodes > 1 UNWIND hashList as hashes` and continue from there

Comment: Thank you @InverseFalcon. I have cleaned up the query a bit with that information. Here is the output of the node that crashes everything (I do see that this is a very dense network centered around this starting point with a lot connections). The top query in the picture crashes. https://i.imgur.com/eFS5eI9.png